# Centering a transform:scaled image

Tags: html, css

I have an `img` that I've scaled to half size via;

```
transform: scale(0.5);
```

[image: example]

As seen above, the result is such that an invisible margin/padding is evident on the top & left of the image (equaling half the size the original image).  Inspecting the resulting `img` in chrome dev tools shows that no margin or padding is evident.

If I know the size of the image prior, I can set `position: absolute` and offset the `top` & `right` values to position it in the center of the container div.  This will not however work with dynamic image sizes.

How can I center the scaled image within the parent div without needing to know the image size prior?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/staff0rd/pen/ampBzz) and snippet:

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #AAA;
}
#image {
  transform: scale(.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="container">
    <img id="image" src="//unsplash.it/500/160?image=10" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected result;

[image]

Comment: remove the transform and check

Comment: Is scale always `.5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If scale is constant `0.5` you can use left/right `50%` and `translate(-100%, -100%)`, width and height of image and container can be dynamic and this will work.

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #AAA;
}
#image {
  transform: scale(.5) translate(-100%, -100%);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="container">
    <img id="image" src="//unsplash.it/500/160?image=10" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `max-width: 100%` to the `#image` seems to center the image inside the container.

```css
#container {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #AAA;
}

#image {
  transform: scale(.5);
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="container">
    <img id="image" src="//unsplash.it/500/160?image=10" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Check it out and let me know your feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers for the snippet edit, for some reason the editor wouldn't show in my browser.  I've updated the question to include the expected result - your answer seems to shrink the image again.

Comment: when you use `max-width: 100%` you would be scaling down by half with respect to the width of the container (you have given a fixed height and width for it)... maybe you should adjust the scale factor...

Comment: The scaling occurs with respect to the image - not the container.  If the original image is 500px wide, then the resulting image should be 250px.

Comment: Well, in that case @NenadVracar 's solution should do fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Your img element is bigger than your container.

use;

```
max-width: 100%;
```

and also;

```
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
```

Comment: Tried this, but `max-width: 100%` seems to shrink/scale the image smaller again.  Not sure what effect `transform-origin` is having.  I've added a screenshot of the expected result to the question.

Comment: Your container has 300px width right? So your image will be the same. And after, you are using scale(.5) exatly half of your parent container. So your image will be 150px width. transform-origin has the effect of where should the transform start. y-x values. top left or bottom right or middle center etc. see here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform-origin/

Comment: The image supplied is 500 width, the transform: scale(0.5) makes it 250px - not 150 px.